# I see a lot of noise and fireflies with Glass BSDF Shader

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, denoise

I made a cube in Blender. The cube has BSDF Glass shader. When I render it there is a lot of noise and fireflies.

I tried everything: Change clamp, change light bounce, denoising, glossy filter, more samples... just everything. I don't know what to do now. When I removed the cube there wasn't noise. The light is point light and in the center of the cube. Blender 2.81 Beta, Cycles.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwrxu.jpg

Comment: Have you tried turning on the denoiser?

Comment: @person132 How to turning it on?

Comment: Did you uncheck **caustics**?

Answer (score 1):

Glass is something that causes a lot of noise in a cycles. While the proper solution is lots of samples, there are some options to get quicker acceptable results.

The first option added to 2.79 is [Denoising](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/cycles/settings/scene/render_layers/denoising.html)

2.81 adds a new denoise composite node that uses [Intels Open Image Denoise](https://openimagedenoise.github.io/). CGCookie has a [look and comparison](https://cgcookie.com/tutorial/denoising-renders-in-blender-2-81?utm_source=blendernation&utm_content=denoising-renders-in-blender-2-81).

There are also third party addons such as [D-Noise](https://remington.pro/software/blender/d-noise/).